# Request always returns null error object

Tags: node.js, http, request, runtime-error

I'm using the [Request](https://github.com/request/request) and standard [Node.js HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) modules to write a simple rest service.

Right now, the server side request handler looks like this:

```
response.writeHead("400","Nope");
response.end();
```

And the client side code looks like this:

```
request.get(href,handleResponse);
function handleResponse(error,response,body) {

   console.log(arguments);
}
```

`response.statusCode` is `400`, but `error` is always `null`.

What do I need to do server side to get the Request module to recognize that the response is an error?

Comment: Related: [Node.js http get request error event not picking up 404 or 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915352/node-js-http-get-request-error-event-not-picking-up-404-or-403)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no error as a request response was received successfully. The error object is only populated if the request itself errors not if a response represents an error. From the documentation: *If any error is encountered during the request (be that with DNS resolution, TCP level errors, or actual HTTP parse errors) an 'error' event is emitted on the returned request object.*

Request --> Successful Response (could represent a remote error) --> response populated

Request --> Error occurs locally or with communication to remote (no response or unrecognized response) --> error populated

Comment: It depends on your POV I suppose but it makes sense from a higher level --> A calls B which responds to A: no error; A calls B which fails to respond A: error. What the response represents is irrelevant as the request/response succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this default behavior. I'm not sure yet, but I may even create some utility methods wrapping `request` to change it. My wrapping callback would be something like :

```
function(connError, httpResponse, body) {
    let error = null;
    if(connError) {
        error = connError;
    } else if(httpResponse.statusCode != 200) {
        error = body;
        body = null;
    }
    finalCallback(error, body);
}
```